# RoR display email without redundant information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, email-headers, mailman-gem

I use Mailman in my RoR projekt

I want to receive mails and display the body ..... but ther is a format error

i get the mail and want to save it as text

```
message = message.body.encoded
```

that works!!!

But the output is not only the body of the mail it also includes
some more infos like

```
f46d04451843a6499e04c08f212a Date: Mon, 21 May 2012 19:29:19 +0200 Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Content-ID: <4fba7b6fa56a0_1e194c540145299d@ubuntu.mail>
```

but that i do not want to disply that infos like Mime, Date .... can someone tell me how in only get the body of the email or how i can cut away the other infos???

Answer (score 0):

Try

> message = message.text_part.body.decoded